# Hibernate MassIndexer and Lucene connexion closes on mariadb

Tags: hibernate, mariadb, lucene

I've got a piece of code that is re-indexing a table of contacts.
This code was running fine until we execute it on a table containing more than 2 millions of contact. In that configuration the process does not run entirely and stop due to the following exception.

```
11/15 16:12:32 ERROR rg.hibernate.search.exception.impl.LogErrorHandler - HSEARCH000058: HSEARCH000211: An exception occurred while the MassIndexer was fetching the primary identifiers list
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not advance using next()
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:48)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
at org.hibernate.internal.ScrollableResultsImpl.convert(ScrollableResultsImpl.java:69)
at org.hibernate.internal.ScrollableResultsImpl.next(ScrollableResultsImpl.java:104)
at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierProducer.loadAllIdentifiers(IdentifierProducer.java:148)
at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierProducer.inTransactionWrapper(IdentifierProducer.java:109)
at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierProducer.run(IdentifierProducer.java:85)
at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.OptionallyWrapInJTATransaction.runWithErrorHandler(OptionallyWrapInJTATransaction.java:69)
at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.ErrorHandledRunnable.run(ErrorHandledRunnable.java:32)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: (conn=18) Server has closed the connection. If result set contain huge amount of data, Server expects client to read off the result set relatively fast. In this case, please consider increasing net_wait_timeout session variable / processing your result set faster (check Streaming result sets documentation for more information)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:234)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.getException(ExceptionMapper.java:165)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.com.read.resultset.SelectResultSet.handleIoException(SelectResultSet.java:381)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.com.read.resultset.SelectResultSet.next(SelectResultSet.java:650)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingResultSet.next(DelegatingResultSet.java:1160)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingResultSet.next(DelegatingResultSet.java:1160)
at org.hibernate.internal.ScrollableResultsImpl.next(ScrollableResultsImpl.java:99)
... 10 more
```

Here is the piece of code :

```
    private void index(EntityManager em, LongConsumer callBack) {
        FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);
        MassIndexer indexer = fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer(Contact.class);
        indexer.batchSizeToLoadObjects(BATCH_SIZE); 
        indexer.threadsToLoadObjects(NB_THREADS); 
        indexer.progressMonitor(new IndexerProgressMonitor(callBack));
        indexer.start();
    }
```

To make the process run until the end and after several unsuccessful tries, the only thing that seems to work is to edit mariadb config file and set : net_write_timeout = 3600

By default the time out is 60 sec here we put it to 1 hour... as the process took 45 minutes...

Does someone have an idea of what we did wrong ?  It does not seems reasonable to set a such huge value to ask a full re-index on the table.

Thanks for your time.
Sylvain